# How to set flask url_for in JQuery

Tags: jquery, flask, url-routing, jinja2

Setting `url_for()`'s in a Jinja2 template is pretty straightforward (as long as it's in the HTML). I've been trying to set it from inside JQuery like so:

```
<script>
    function my_func(key) {
        var newHref = sprintf("{{url_for('fig', selector='%s')}}", key);
        $('#my_id').attr('href', newHref);
    }
<script>
```

Where `sprintf` is just a standard string formatting function for JQuery.

Nothing happens now.

I also tried it with an `onClick` function instead of an `href`. It looked like this:

```
function my_Clicked(key) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: sprintf("{{ url_for('fig', selector = '%s')}}", key)
    });
}
```

Again, nothing happens when the `<button>` is clicked.

Is this even possible? The Jinja2/Flask markers `{{ }}` only seem to appear in the HTML and a processed when the page is loaded. However, I don't see why it isn't possible that you set a dynamic URL after the page has loaded, so that when you click it, the request is just sent back to the server.

---

**EDIT**
After using the extension suggested by odai alghamdi, I have reached a perplexing problem.

I am going with an `onClick` AJAX call for the `<button>`. It now looks like this:

```
function cropzoneClicked(key) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: flask_util.url_for('fig', {selector:key})
    });
}
```

However, nothing happens when the button is clicked. I know that the function is being called because I can stick an alert in there. But, nothing is being rendered and the `'GET'` request isn't returning a successful callback

Comment: Use this extension to do it : https://github.com/dantezhu/flask_util_js

Comment: What URL is generated? `var newHref = sprintf("what/is/here", key);`?

Comment: Well, I'm still trying to get it to work. My satisfaction was a little premature. Plus, you've only commented, so I can't accept :)

Comment: If you still facing problems , tell us :) gd luck

Comment: Just to double check, are you rendering the template that is generating the JavaScript code?  By that, I mean if you look at the source code from the browser, do you see something in the place of the {{ }} tag?

Comment: @Doobeh, So when I look at my page source, `sprintf("{{ url_for('fig', selector = '%s')}}", key)` becomes `sprintf("/fig/%25s", key)`. So, I guess the answer to your question is, yes

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here goes with an example, I never really considered needing `url_for` to be accessed from the user-interface, but it's good to know how.  When you click on a button, it'll use the `id` as the key to the `url_for` and show the resulting URL in an alert box.

### requirements.txt

```
flask
git://github.com/dantezhu/flask_util_js.git
```

Then install them, `pip install -r requirements.txt` into your virtualenv.

### app.py

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask_util_js import FlaskUtilJs

app = Flask(__name__)
fujs = FlaskUtilJs(app)


@app.context_processor
def inject_fujs():
    return dict(fujs=fujs)

@app.route('/')
def home():
    return render_template('example.html')

@app.route('/foo/<something>/')
def something(something):
    return 'Alright then {}'.format(something)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

### example.html

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
    {{ fujs.js }}

    <script>
        $( document ).ready(function(){

            $("button").on("click", function() {
                var $button = $( this );
                var url = flask_util.url_for('something', {something: $button.attr('id') });
                alert(url);
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <button id="button_a">First!</button>
    <button id="button_b">Second!</button>
    <button id="button_c">Third!</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: First off, thanks for the detailed answer. I've sort of come to the same place. I can generate the correct url, and then I try to set the button's `href` to the new URL with `$('#myButton').attr('href', newHref);`. (I also tried a GET request as you can see in my question). The problem is, nothing happens when I click the button after I supposedly change the href

Comment: Cool, I got it. It didn't work with href or with a GET request, so I just said `windown.location = newURL;`. Easy as that. Still don't get why the other methods didn't work, but hey, at least it runs! Thanks

Comment: Just replace the `alert(url);` line with `$(location).attr('href',url);` and it'll send the user to the url, rather then display it in an alert box.